# cannot install 16.04 on HP dv9000

Tags: boot

Cannot install ubuntu 16.04/16.04.1 on HP pavilion dv9000, message soon after start
"nonblocking pool is initialized"
after that message installation hangs. 
ubuntu 16.10 hangs after the message "crng init done".

I argue there is a problem with Kernel 4. I can install ubuntu versions previous to 16.04, but it hangs after update.

Is there any solution?

Regards